# Calculating VBox dimensions before first render

Tags: javafx, vbox

I am attempting to translate a VBox's X,Y before displaying it on the pane.

Problem is, when using vBox.getHeight(), I always get 0.0 before the vBox is actually rendered.

Is there a way to be able to retrieve these dimensions dynamically so I can translate the VBox before render?

Comment: How to do this depends a little on why you want the height. I'm guessing you want to animate the `VBox` when first displaying it. If you know the `VBox` will be laid out at its preferred height, you can call `prefHeight(-1)`. If you want to modify the layout of the containing pane, it's probably better to subclass `Pane` and override `layoutChildren()`.